# Way to auto-group existing photos into events?

Tags: icloud, photos.app, photo-stream

I migrated from primarily a PC desktop to a Macbook Pro, and with that, brought along 10+ years of digital photos. On my PC, I had each 'event' grouped into sub-folder by date, so that worked out well importing into iPhoto-- but I also had iCloud setup on my PC, and it was syncing my Photostream (into just one big folder, with 1800+ photos). Bringing this over to iPhoto I now have "one event" named Photostream that has all these photos. Is there any way to have iPhoto just automatically group these by date into new events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! If you select the "big event" in "Events" view, then go to the menu, "Events" -> "Autosplit Selected Events" it will automagically split the one event into the many events.

Answer (score 0):

In iPhoto > Preferences > General there is an option "Autosplit into Events" that you can set.

If all you are seeing is the one Photostream event, I'd guess that it isn't finished importing and it will split the events when it is done.

I don't have a photostream event in my events in iPhoto, I just have an iCloud tab that is on the same level in the sidebar as Events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did use that option, but it appears to not work for importing a folder into iPhoto, because iPhoto just used the folder names for event names.

Comment: The "Events" tab on the side should be separate from a folder/album. Is this "Photostream" event appearing when you click on events, or is it underneath "Albums" farther down? What if you click on "Last 12 Months"?

Comment: The "Photostream" is an actual event, named the same as the folder that iPhoto imported. It is not an album. I do not have any albums listed.

Comment: huh, that's weird. When you click "Last 12 Months" does it just have that one event there too?

Comment: iPhoto literally created an event for each folder I imported. So I have many events, some of them are already "correct" (because my original folder was named with a date), and others, like the "Photostream" folder, just contain a ton of images, that I need to break up into more logical events.

Comment: For fun I just exported all of the photos and re-imported them, and they just came in again as one big event, named after the folder.